# writing into file using VFS -WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, file-writing, wso2-esb

This sequence is for writing one specific field value into the file.Problem is we only need content,but using xml label is coming and if I use json then value comes into {}`

```
                             {$1}

                       </format>
                       <args>
                          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//FieldValue"/>
                       </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                    <send>
                       <endpoint name="FileEpr">`target path`
                          <address uri="vfs:file://D:/Documents/File/out"/>
                       </endpoint>
                    </send>
                 </Sequence>
```

1.My question is is there any way to write content only??
2.In this code I used payload factory,is there any way to write into a file using some other mediator??
Please suggest how yo write into a file **without using payload factory**

Comment: I want to convert in from base64 to binary,can you suggest anything?? @Jean-Michel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whatever method to apply your transformation : payloadFactory, javascript, XSL, custom class, ...

If what you call "content only" is a way to produce a text file, you must generate (with your transformation) a xml message with a soap body like this :

```
<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">your text payload</text>
```

Sample with payloadFactory :

```
            <payloadFactory>
               <format>
                 <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:text>
               </format>
               <args>
                  <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//FieldValue/text()"/>
               </args>
            </payloadFactory>
```

Before send mediator, think to specify message format so that WSO2 ESB can choose the right message formatter :

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/plain; charset=windows-1252" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: thanks.its working.
If we need to write into binary format,how we can achieve that.could you please provide the code??